# wasysym symbols render to something different

Tags: symbols, packages

I would like to use the wasysym package to get access to characters such as lightning and clock. However, the following MWE for me gives different symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}
$\lightning\clock$
\end{document}
```

This results in the following when I run `pdflatex` on it.

[image]

That is, lightning is instead rendered to a backtick and clock is instead rendered to a 0.

I have TeXLive 2012 on Ubuntu 12.04 and the same shows up when using Evince or Okular to view. I do not know if this is a problem with my LaTeX code or with my TeX installation or some encoding problem particular to my machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `mathmode`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}
\lightning\clock
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't have much idea on `mathmode`. But here is a workaround using `\text` from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,wasysym}
\begin{document}
\lightning\clock $\text{\lightning}$
\end{document}
```

Or use `\mbox{}` --- `$\mbox{\lightning}$` as noted by Gonzalo.

Comment: Thanks. Where are those symbols defined in mathmode? that is, why lighning goes to backtick and not something else and why doesnt it give me an error? Also, how can I use lightning in math mode?

Comment: @XuWang You can load `amsmath` (before `wasysym`)and enclose it in a `\text{}` macro, e.g. `$x^{\text{\lightning}}$`

Comment: No need to load `amsmath` and use `\text`; a simple `\mbox` is enough: `$\mbox{\lightning}$`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- although the original example doesn't use these symbols as superscripts, one of the comments to the answer does, and for that use, unless `\lightning` is wanted at full size (yech!), `amsmath` and `\text` are more appropriate than `\mbox`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton sure; I suggested `\mbox` since the OP didn't mention the use as super/subscript; (the comment that mentions the use as superscript is not from the OP).