# Why does \mathbb{R} cause '! Undefined control sequence. - \GenericError'?

Tags: pgfplots, errors

When I compile the following document, I get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.39 ...an, y=variance, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
                                                  ^^M
?
```

But when I change `\mathbb{R}` to `mathbb{R}` everything is fine. And the document also compiles when I put $\mathbb{R}$ over the tikz picture.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} %layout

\usepackage{filecontents}  % only for this question

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
label,mean,variance
B,0.66,0.14
C,0.85,0.17
\pi,1.29,0.35
\mathbb{R},0.75,0.22
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            width=15cm, height=8cm,
            xlabel=mean,
            ylabel=variance,
            visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \label},
            every node near coord/.append style={font={\tiny}},
            nodes near coords={$\label$},
         ]
          \addplot[scatter,
                   mark=x,only marks,
                   mark size=1,
                   ]
                   table [x=mean, y=variance, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's an expansion issue; see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195080/using-latex-commands-inside-pgfplotsset  .  I don't know how to fix it in your case, though.

Comment: @percusse Or, maybe better, `\noexpand\protect\noexpand` (which works).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`pgfplots` extensively uses `\edef` and it's not easy to find which one is responsible for this.

My suggestion is to redefine `\mathbb` so it uses `\protected` instead of the traditional LaTeX protection mechanism, which fails in `\edef`. The `\protected` method, instead, is safe.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} %layout

\usepackage{filecontents}  % only for this question

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}% why not 1.11?

% redefine \mathbb to be a \protected macro rather than a `robust' command
\protected\edef\mathbb{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \csname mathbb \endcsname
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
label,mean,variance
B,0.66,0.14
C,0.85,0.17
\pi,1.29,0.35
\mathbb{R},0.75,0.22
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            width=15cm, height=8cm,
            xlabel=mean,
            ylabel=variance,
            visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \label},
            every node near coord/.append style={font={\tiny}},
            nodes near coords={$\label$},
         ]
          \addplot[scatter,
                   mark=x,only marks,
                   mark size=1,
                   ]
                   table [x=mean, y=variance, col sep=comma] {\jobname.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, `pgfplots` should probably use `\protected@edef` instead of `\edef`.

[image]

If you have several commands that need this kind of workaround, it's better to use `etoolbox` and its `\robustify` function:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify{\mathbb}
```

will do the same as in the above code.

Comment: Is `\sun` from `wasysym` the same problem? At least the error is another one: `! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.49     \end{axis}
`

Comment: @moose That's why I said `pgfplots` should use `\protected@edef` and not `\edef`. Look at my edit for an abstraction of the workaround.

Comment: Thanks. That made some more work. But `\lightning` from `stmaryrd` combined with other symbols from `wasysym` still has problems. That might be related to [wasysym symbols render to something different](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80053/5645)